# reader.GetSchemaTable on Oracle database does not return a DataTypeName column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, types, getschematable

Doing a table = reader.GetSchemaTable(); on sql server 2005 returns me a column DataTypeName to find out the datatype of my select statement.

Doing the same code on a oracle server returns me NO DataTypeName column.

How do you then get the datatype name for a column1 field using a select column1 from tablename statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Well which reader are you using, there is `OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable` [Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getschematable.aspx) which should give what you want

Comment: have to use the DbDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

When using Oracle, DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable doesn't work.

You can use OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable.

Another option would be to iterate thorugh DbDataReader fields, like this:

```
    public bool Test(DbDataReader _dr, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= _dr.FieldCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((_dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
               //Change this to your needs
               _dr.GetDataTypeName(i);
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```